# Subversion: How put external repositorie in root folder?

Tags: svn, merge, external, root, repository

I have a 'web-page' and  'lib' repositories.

```
/web-page
    index.php
    some.js
    /some-directory

/lib
    class-file.php
    class-database.php
    config.php
    /imgs
        [...]files
    /js
        [...]files
    /css
        [...]files
```

And I want to merge on windows folder c:\work\ like this:

```
C:\work
    index.php
    index.php
    some.js
    /some-directory
    class-file.php
    class-database.php
    config.php
    /imgs
        [...]files
    /js
        [...]files
    /css
        [...]files
```

I make a folder c:\work, I put inside a repository web-page. But when I tray to add an external repositorie ( like 'lib' ) I use menu: [Tortoise>propierties>New>Externals>New] and I can't left blank the field LOCAL PATH, I try with '^', '^/', '//', '/', '\', '\' and only works when I select one by one folder and put path from root 'c:[...]work'. I want to use a referencial name.

Thanks for your help!

I use:
TortoiseSVN 1.8.8, Build 25755 - 64 Bit , 2014/08/10 14:44:06
Subversion 1.8.10, -release

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Main error**

You can not collect in one target folder two externals: each external is nested Working Copy, linked to single URL

**Additional error**

You can not define `LOCALPATH` as "this folder" (`.`), only as some child

Even with *formally correct* definitions for your case

```
../Exts/ext1 common
../Exts/ext2 common
```

svn ps will fail

```
>svn ps svn:externals -F z:\ext.txt .
svn: E155041: Invalid svn:externals property on 'Z:\WC\trunk': target 'common' appears more than once
```

Comment: yes, I try to do example but by logic, every proyect must be control ther folder. thanks. Now I need move al references..